# About the topology textbook.

Tags: general-topology, soft-question

I'm trying to study topology.
I got two books, one written by croom and another one written by munkres
Which one do you think is better for the beginner? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I second the suggestion of @alkabary of using Munkres (this was the book that furnished my first introduction to topology).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say munkrees is better for a first expose to topology.It is comprehensive and does not assume any background in the subject. Also it is a standard textbook for many universities / colleges. And for most of the questions in munkrees , you will be able to find help on the internet or here unlike the other textbook